# Roth counting toward 401k maximum

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, roth-401k, vanguard, limits

Vanguard is [showing me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6uGL.png) that my Roth contributions are counting toward the $19,000 401k maximum. I thought Roth counted towards a separate $6000 maximum.

Is my Roth not an IRA?

Comment: Also, congratulations on making over $170,000

Answer (score 2):

There are *Roth 401(k)* and *Roth IRA*.

Roth 401(k)- where you contribute from your salary - are a part of the 19000 $ 401k limit. Roth IRA are separate.
Yours seems to be a Roth 401(k)so the limit applies. You can open a separate Roth IRA and there you have the extra limit.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Roth portion of your 401(k) is not an IRA.

If you want to contribute to a Roth IRA, you have to specifically open a Roth IRA account.

Comment: And the annual limit for contributions to IRA (trad and Roth combined if you have both) is currently $5,500 or if age 50 up $6,500 (not $6,000 in either case) except you can't do Roth IRA at all (except via 'backdoor') if MAGI over $199k joint or $135k single/separate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Incorrect. IRA contributions limit for 2019 is $6000, or $7000 if you’re age 50 or older.

Comment: @void_ptr: gack -- you're right if I search out the IRB notice, but why didn't they put it in p590a where I looked and it _obviously_ belongs? :-(

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Do you have a 590A for 2019?  A lot of the publications have been slow to update this year (not sure if it is abnormal or they are always this slow)

Comment: @BenVoigt: with a few exceptions like p15 and p505, annual pubs are updated at the end of the tax year, usually Nov-Jan; 2018 p590a in particular was released Dec. 31 2018. But they contain 'what's new' sections for the upcoming year as well as the past year when applicable, and 2018 p590a does have 'what's new for 2019' with the changed phaseout amounts but NOT this change in the contribution limit.